# Followed IG scraping Tutorial and stuck on XPath/other issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, instagram

I've been working off this tutorial here: https://medium.com/swlh/tutorial-web-scraping-instagrams-most-precious-resource-corgis-235bf0389b0c

When I try to create a simpler version of function "insta_details", that would get the likes and comments of an Instagram photo post, I can't seem to tell what's gone wrong with the code. I think I'm using the xpaths wrongly (first time), but the error message is calling for "NoSuchElementException".

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


def insta_details(urls):
    browser = Chrome()
    post_details = []
    for link in urls:
        browser.get(link)
        likes = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('likes').text
        age = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a time').text
        xpath_comment = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div'
        comment = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_comment).text
        insta_link = link.replace('https://www.instagram.com/p', '')
        post_details.append({'link': insta_link,'likes/views': likes,'age': age, 'comment': comment})
    return post_details


urls = ['https://www.instagram.com/p/CFdNu1lnCmm/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CFYR2OtHDbD/']
insta_details(urls)
```

Error Message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"likes"}
```

Copying and pasting the code from the tutorial hasn't worked for me yet. Am I calling the function wrongly or is there something else in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the tutorial it seems like your code is incomplete.

Here, try this:

```
import time
import re
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


def find_mentions_or_hashtags(comment, pattern):
    mentions = re.findall(pattern, comment)
    if (len(mentions) > 1) & (len(mentions) != 1):
        return mentions
    elif len(mentions) == 1:
        return mentions[0]
    else:
        return ""


def insta_link_details(url):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    browser = Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    browser.get(url)
    try:
        # This captures the standard like count.
        likes = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            """/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/article/
                div[3]/section[2]/div/div/button/span""").text.split()[0]
        post_type = 'photo'
    except:
        # This captures the like count for videos which is stored
        likes = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            """/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/article/
                div[3]/section[2]/div/span/span""").text.split()[0]
        post_type = 'video'
    age = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a time').text
    comment = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        """/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/
        div[3]/div[1]/ul/div/li/div/div/div[2]/span""").text

    hashtags = find_mentions_or_hashtags(comment, '#[A-Za-z]+')
    mentions = find_mentions_or_hashtags(comment, '@[A-Za-z]+')
    post_details = {'link': url, 'type': post_type, 'likes/views': likes,
                    'age': age, 'comment': comment, 'hashtags': hashtags,
                    'mentions': mentions}
    time.sleep(10)
    return post_details


for url in ['https://www.instagram.com/p/CFdNu1lnCmm/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CFYR2OtHDbD/']:
    print(insta_link_details(url))
```

Output:

```
{'link': 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CFdNu1lnCmm/', 'type': 'photo', 'likes/views': '4', 'age': '6h', 'comment': 'Natural ingredients for natural skincare is the best way to go, with:\n\nThe Body Shop @thebodyshopaust\n☘️The Beauty Chef @thebeautychef\n\nWalk your body to a happier, healthier you with The Body Shop’s fair trade, high quality products. Be a powerhouse of digestive health with The Beauty Chef’s ingenious food supplements.  Even at our busiest, there’s always a way to take care of our health. \n\n5% rebate on all online purchases with #sosure. T&Cs apply. All rates for limited time only.', 'hashtags': '#sosure', 'mentions': ['@thebodyshopaust', '@thebeautychef']}
{'link': 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CFYR2OtHDbD/', 'type': 'photo', 'likes/views': '10', 'age': '2 DAYS AGO', 'comment': 'The weather can dry out your skin and hair this season, and there’s no reason to suffer through more when there’s so much going on!  Look better, feel better and brush better with these great offers for haircare, skin rejuvenation and beauty  Find 5% rewards for purchases at:\n\n Shaver Shop\n Fresh Fragrances\n Happy Hair Brush\n & many more online at our website bio !\n\nSoSure T&Cs apply. All rates for limited time only.\n.\n.\n.\n#sosure #sosureapp #haircare #skincare #perfume #beauty #healthylifestyle #shavershop #freshfragrances #happyhairbrush #onlineshopping #deals #melbournelifestyle #australia #onlinedeals', 'hashtags': ['#sosure', '#sosureapp', '#haircare', '#skincare', '#perfume', '#beauty', '#healthylifestyle', '#shavershop', '#freshfragrances', '#happyhairbrush', '#onlineshopping', '#deals', '#melbournelifestyle', '#australia', '#onlinedeals'], 'mentions': ''}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!! I will be combing your code in detail to find out more. Thank you again for your help!